# Zone parsing for GMT0

Tags: java, java-time

I have GMT0 as the default timezone in a system and it causes problem when I'm serializing it and deserializing it just after that.

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone","GMT0");
DateTimeFormatter zoneFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendZoneOrOffsetId()
            .toFormatter();
String formatted = zoneFormatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now());
System.out.println(formatted);
System.out.println(zoneFormatter.parse(formatted));
```

The first `System.out.println` prints `GMT0` while the second throws the following problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'GMT0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 3
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
```

is it an expected behavior? Is there a way to do that in a safe manner?

Comment: thanks @OleV.V. However I would prefer to avoid changing that since it has impacts on other applications.

Comment: The funny thing is I cannot reproduce your problem (only noticed now). On my Java 10.0.1 your code prints `GMT0` and then `{},ISO,GMT0`.

Comment: I have reproduced. On Java 1.8.0_131 I get the same exception as you report. On Java 9 I don’t.

Comment: Indeed it's a bug in the JVM https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8138664, seems not fixed in 8

Comment: Workarounds include: (1) Move to Java 9 or later (well, that’s not always a walk in the park, though). (2) Set default to `GMT` or `UTC` (without the  `0`). There are probably more…

Comment: If you can explain the real-life context where you need to parse the default zone ID, I’d like to consider ways to obtain what you want.

Comment: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1952 ;-) I think I'll extend the codec provided by Cassandra to handle correctly what is persisted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178603/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-nicolas-henneaux).

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed in the comments, that's a [bug in JDK 8](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8138664), fixed only in versions >= 9.

If you're using JDK 8 and can't/won't upgrade it, there's a workaround. You can treat the "GMT" part as a literal (the text `"GMT"` itself) and consider the 0 as the offset seconds, using the respective `ChronoField`:

```
DateTimeFormatter zoneParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // text "GMT"
    .appendLiteral("GMT")
    // offset seconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS)
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(zoneParser.parse("GMT0"));
```

Keep in mind that this works **only** for offset zero. For any other values (such as "GMT2" or "GMT-2") this won't work, because it'll consider the values "2" and "-2" as seconds, but they actually mean "hours".

---

#### In case you need to parse all offset values in this format ("GMTn")

Well, JDK 8 also [can't handle one-digit offsets](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066806), and it always requires a signal, either `+` or `-`. So "GMT2" and "GMT-2" won't work with the current API.

There's a harder alternative, though: create your own `TemporalField`, representing "offset hours". All the details about how to do it are in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html), and I'm not sure if all methods are correctly implemented - I'm just sure about `isSupportedBy`, `getFrom` and `adjustInto`, the others maybe need some improvement/adjustment:

```
public class OffsetHours implements TemporalField {

    @Override
    public TemporalUnit getBaseUnit() {
        return ChronoUnit.HOURS;
    }

    @Override
    public TemporalUnit getRangeUnit() {
        return ChronoUnit.FOREVER;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueRange range() {
        return ValueRange.of(ZoneOffset.MIN.getTotalSeconds() / 3600, ZoneOffset.MAX.getTotalSeconds() / 3600);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDateBased() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTimeBased() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedBy(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        return temporal.isSupported(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public ValueRange rangeRefinedBy(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        ValueRange rangeInSecs = temporal.range(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS);
        return ValueRange.of(rangeInSecs.getMinimum() / 3600, rangeInSecs.getMaximum() / 3600);
    }

    @Override
    public long getFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        return temporal.getLong(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS) / 3600;
    }

    @Override
    public <R extends Temporal> R adjustInto(R temporal, long newValue) {
        return (R) temporal.with(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, newValue * 3600);
    }
}
```

Now you create an instance of this field and use it in your parser:

```
// the new field
OffsetHours offsetHoursField = new OffsetHours();
DateTimeFormatter zoneParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // text "GMT"
    .appendLiteral("GMT")
    // offset hours
    .appendValue(offsetHoursField)
    .toFormatter();
```

I also recommend creating a `TemporalQuery` to convert the parsed result to a `ZoneOffset`:

```
// get hours and create offset from hours value
TemporalQuery<ZoneOffset> getOffsetFromHours = temporal -> {
    return ZoneOffset.ofHours((int) temporal.getLong(offsetHoursField));
};
```

Now you can parse it:

```
ZoneOffset offsetZero = zoneParser.parse("GMT0", getOffsetFromHours);
ZoneOffset offsetTwo = zoneParser.parse("GMT2", getOffsetFromHours);
ZoneOffset offsetMinusTwo = zoneParser.parse("GMT-2", getOffsetFromHours);
```

You can improve it letting the `OffsetHours` field to be a static instance (or maybe an `enum`), so you don't need to create it all the time.

Comment: I believe that the `0` in `GMT0` refers to an offset in hours, not seconds. As long as we’re sure it’s 0, it doesn’t matter, of course, but then we absolutely need to check this assumption explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, the [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) is responsible for handling timezone names and aliases according to [IANA Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) (often referred as TZ DB, zdata). In particular, [ZoneId.html#of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) is used for that conversion.

Different TZ DB versions are shipped by Oracle with different JREs: see [tzdata versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) and [overview of how to update tzdata](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/timezones-137583.html)

The list of TZ DB identifiers is available [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List) (TZ column), as for release release 2017c, `GMT0` is already listed as deprecated in there, and canonical name for this time zone is `Etc/GMT`

Despite there is no explicit instructions to use only canonical TZ names, it can be a best practice however, as deprecated aliases may be removed from further tzdata distributions (and thus from Zone.of support) without any special notice